# Suppress bold when using "__"

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm creating a R-Markdown file, where I have a table which contains the path to the files used in the script. Some of the files can contain "__" in their name. The text, which is between such two occurances is then displayed in a bold font. How can I suppress this behaviour?

E.g.

```markdown
"C:/usr/xxx/B___file.txt, C:/usr/xxx/C___file.txt"
```

will be shown as

> "C:/usr/xxx/B_**file.txt, C:/usr/xxx/C**_file.txt"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape the special characters using `\`:

```
C:/usr/xxx/B\_\_file.txt, …
```

Better yet, mark file paths up as *inline code*:

```markdown
`C:/usr/xxx/B__file.txt`, …
```

This will change the way they’re rendered (namely, as inline code) but in general that’s the desired result.

Comment: The file paths aren't hard coded, so I would have to str_replace the special character with \_? The second part is difficult, im creating a tibble, which is then displayed using knittr::kable, I wouldn't know how to mark strings as inline code inside a tibble

Comment: @MG92 Yes, `str_replace` would work. Some table rendering libraries (particularly ‘pander’) also allow doing this automatically, though I don’t think `knitr::kable` does. Anyway, I don’t understand the second part of your comment: why would marking the paths as inline be any more difficult than escaping special characters?

Comment: Maybe I wrote the second part a little confusing, I tried using the second methond (adding the inline code character before and after the string) and it worked perfectly. The first method with str_replace_all didn't work however, the result was still the same